# Custom fixed bar width in Plotly Express, Python 3

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am trying to deal with axis labels overlapping by having the axis width dynamical in my horizontal bar plot:

```
fig = px.bar(df, orientation='h')   

fig.update_layout(
     yaxis_nticks = len(df.columns),
     height = len(df.columns)*30,
     ).update_xaxes(automargin = True,
     ).update_yaxes(automargin = True)
```

For some reason it works fine just with some df shape, when the shape is smaller, `yaxis` labels overlap again.

Having dynamical size of the `yaxis` does not work for me then. Is there a way how to have the bars width fixed in Plotly Express? I found it just for Plotly GO which I do not want to use.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The bar width can be specified in `update_traces`:

```
fig = px.bar(df, orientation='h').update_traces(width = 0.7)
```

Hoping this helps some one.